# Function, that creates other functions c++

Tags: c++, task, function-pointers

I have a task to create function Factory(const std::string name) that returns pointer to function without arguments that prints name. Also I should use only native language methods (without lambda functions and etc). Could you give me example?

Comment: "native language methods"? What do you even mean? Also, asking for off-site resources is off-topic.

Comment: Well lambdas *are* what I would call a "native language method", as it's an integral part of the C++ language.

Comment: As for this *specific* case it's very easy to create a class with a function-call operator that does exactly what you want, and return an instance of that (with the right constructor it will make your `Factor` function into a single-line function, containing only a suitable `return` statement).

Comment: My teacher sad not to use lambda function and std::function

Comment: Lastly, please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: But could you give me example of this class?

Comment: @JekyllHyde : what was the last lesson that you had before he gave you the homework ? :D

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd Point taken :-) I should probably have left more things unresolved.

Answer (score 1):

Annotations in the code. I deliberately did not make it print to std::cout directly but instead it will return the string. Adapt it as you please.

```
#include <iostream>

struct bork {              // the object to hold the text to return
    std::string text;      // the text to return

    // constructor
    bork(const std::string& in) : text(in) {}

    // the operator that makes the object behave like a function    
    std::string operator ()(void) const { return text; }

    // a factory method to create a "bork"
    static bork make_bork(const std::string& text) {
        return bork(text);
    }

};

int main() {
    auto a = bork::make_bork("howdy");
    auto b = bork::make_bork("world");

    std::cout << a() << "\n";
    std::cout << b() << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot create a function in a function. The only way is to know all the strings there will appear and having a functions for each possible string, and then select and return the proper function. Or else you can use objects :-)